# Пере-скачивание обновлений Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Как мне скачать заново обновления для `Windows 10`? Обновления скачались, но скачались битые. Как бы мне их удалить и скачать заново чтобы уже установились наконец. Пробовал удалять все из папки `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download`, не помогает. Перезагрузка компьютера превращается в очень долгий процесс. Минут 20 обновляется до 98%, потом сообщение мол "мы не смогли установить обновления. Откат изменений". И еще минут 20 откатывает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для виндовс-10 нажми сочетание клавиш на клавиатуре, в английской раскладке **WIN+X** --> далее выбери пункт меню **Программы и компоненты** . В левой части экрана нажми ссылку **Просмотр установленных обновлений**.

*Если система вообще не грузится, советую поставить новую систему на отформатированный диск или на отдельный логический раздел, одного физического диска.*

Comment: Действительно, спасибо. Нашел внизу пункт "нет данных". Удалил это обновление, помогло